# How to stop an SVG animation at a certain point(s)?

Tags: javascript, flash, svg

I'm tasked with creating an animation in Flash/Animate that will be exported as an SVG onto a web page. The intended functionality of the SVG animation is that it has a few points where it stops automatically and the user can navigate to these points by clicking on a navigation button. This would move the animation back or forth, depending on where one is at the time.

So, I would like to stop the animation just as if there was a stop(); function call at the frame where the animation should stop.

Is there a way to do this?

If not, a possible solution would be to split the animations between the stop points, but that presents a problem of its own:

Say the animation was at the first stop in the animation, A. The user clicks the animation to point C, which means that the animation would have to go from A to B and then, at the end of part B, proceed to animate B to C. Hope this makes sense. I suppose this is achievable by some JavaScript wizardry, but it's a bit of a band-aid.

Comment: What kind of animation? For SMIL there's [pauseAnimations](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations)

Comment: How do you mean what kind of an animation?

I spotted pauseAnimations in one example, but in that it required the user to click a pause button and then restart it with play. What I would need is that I can somehow set a milestone in a certain part of the animation where the pauseAnimations occurs on its own.

Comment: You can animate things lots of different ways e.g. SMIL, CSS transitions, raw javascript.  With SMIL you'd just have 2 animations. You'd begin the second on some kind of trigger.

Comment: It seems that CSS might be the key, if it can indeed control SVG. The CSS part is a bit more unknown area for me so will have to study a bit. That being said, if [this](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/css_animations) stuff can be applied to control at least the direction of the animation, it might be the way.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible directly using svg. However as you said you can use multiple stop points. You could then use a onclick event where if one animation id is clicked it starts the selected animation but hides other id's belonging to other animations.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation as well as your reply. I think I will make a case to change the navigation method for something less cumbersome.